# How to get at the information from a SQLite table containing two foreign keys referencing the same column

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

As part of a personal project, I have built a database which contains a table of text files (with their path and basename as columns), and another table, which indicates which files are duplicates of other files.

Here's how the first table looks :

```
files(
         filesid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
         filename TEXT,
         filesource TEXT,
         path TEXT UNIQUE)
```

And here's the second one :

```
duplicatefiles(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
            filesid INTEGER,
            duplicateof INTEGER,
            songid INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY(filesid) REFERENCES lyricsfiles(filesid),
            FOREIGN KEY(duplicateof) REFERENCES lyricsfiles(filesid),
```

This last table has two columns of foreign keys referencing ids in the files table, indicating that the two files are duplicate from each other.

I did this to minimize information duplication but I now realise that I have no idea how to query this table to get what I actually want, which is the path to both files.
I have read about aliases, but I have been unable to find documentation on how to use them in this case.

I'm using sqlite3 and python3.

So my questions are : what's the correct way to query the database as it is to get at the information I need ? And what would be a better way to represent this information in a database ?

Comment: Instead of two tables, why not just add a column (example: parent_filesid) to the original table? Will the filesid be different for duplicate files?

Comment: I'm more familiar with TSQL (maybe sqlite3 is as well) but can't you just use a `JOIN` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to join your table `files` 2 times. To do so you need table aliases:

```
SELECT
  ORI.filesid original_filesid
 ,ORI.filename original_filename
 ,ORI.filesource original_filesource
 ,DUP.filesid duplicate_filesid
 ,DUP.filename duplicate_filename
 ,DUP.filesource duplicate_filesource
FROM duplicatefiles DPF
JOIN files ORI
ON ORI.filesid = DPF.duplicateof
JOIN files DUP
ON DUP.filesid = DPF.filesid
```

you see that i joined `files` as the alias ORI indicating that this alias represents the original file (also see the join condition `ORI.filesid = DPF.duplicateof`). The duplicates are joined via the tables alias DUP. Using the alias you then select the field you want and you could also rename them for better understanding `ORI.filesid` is renamed to `original_filesid`.